# Oracle 11g Listener will not start even though the windows service is started

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a fresh install of Oracle 11g (11.2.0.4). I have a listener (LWORK) configured. In my services snapin, I see the service OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListenerLWORK and it is started and set to automatically start.

However, I get an **ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error** when I try to connect with SQLPlus.

When I try to TNSPing the Database SID (WORKSID), I get:

```
Used parameter files:
C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name
```

When I run lsnrctl start LWORK I get **Message 1070 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNSTNS-12557: Message 12557 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS TNS-12560: Message 12560 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS  TNS-00527: Message 527 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS** errors.

I'm at my wits end with this. I've been fighting it for three work days now.

Comment: show the content of your listener.ora

Comment: Actually, I ended up wiping the server because the registry got corrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I ended up wiping the server because the registry got corrupt.